St. Faustina on Spiritually "Sharing" or "Breaking the Wafer"
Consider the following entries (not a complete list) in St. Faustina's Diary in which a spiritual sharing or breaking of the wafer is noted.

Christmas Eve, 1935. From early morning, my spirit was immersed in God. His presence pervaded my whole being. In the evening, before supper, I went to the chapel for a minute to share the wafer, at the feet of Jesus, with those who are far away and whom Jesus loves greatly and to whom I owe so much. Just as I was spiritually sharing the wafer with a certain person [probably Father Sopocko], I heard these words within me: His heart is, for Me, a heaven on earth. When I was leaving the chapel, in an instant, God's omnipotence enveloped me. I understood how greatly God loves us. Oh, if people could at least partly comprehend and understand this! (574)


... Christmas Eve, [1933].  ... In the evening, before the ceremony of the breaking of the wafer, I went into the chapel to break the wafer, in spirit, with my loved ones, and I asked the Mother of God for graces for them. ... (182)


[December 1937].  Today during confession, breaking the wafer with me spiritually, he gave me the following wishes: "Be as faithful as you can to the grace of God; secondly, beg God's mercy for yourself and for the whole world, because we are all in great need of God's mercy." (1432)


Christmas Eve [1937]. After Holy Communion, the Mother of God gave me to experience the anxious concern she had in Her heart because of the Son of God. But this anxiety was permeated with such fragrance of abandonment to the will of God that I should call it rather a delight than an anxiety. ... (1437)


[December 1937] Before supper, I went into the chapel for a moment to break the wafer spiritually with those beloved persons, so dear to my heart, though far away. First, I steeped myself in profound prayer and asked the Lord for graces for them all as a group and then for each one individually. Jesus gave me to know how much this pleased Him, and my soul was filled with even greater joy to see that God loves in a special way those whom we love. (1438)

QUESTION: What does it mean to (spiritually) "Share the Wafer" or "Break the Wafer"? Is it a Polish custom, i.e. only in Poland?

St. Faustina on Spiritually "Sharing" or "Breaking the Wafer"?
The Catholic Church in Poland and in a few other Eastern European countries have a well established tradition of sharing the wafer, usually in and around the time of Christmas.
This tradition is a symbolism of genuine reconciliation.

Breaking of the Christmas wafer (opłatek) constitutes one of the most important traditions accompanying the celebration of Christmas in Poland. The custom is practiced during a ceremonial Christmas Eve supper (Wigilia) on the 24th of December.
Christmas wafer (opłatek) is a very thin white bread wafer, unleavened and unsalted, baked from white flour and without yeast. The custom of sharing the Christmas wafer is known also in Slovakia, Lithuania, Belarus, Ukraine, Czech Republic and Italy. It began in Poland in the late 18th century.
Christmas wafer (opłatek) is a symbol of reconciliation, friendship and love. Sharing it at the beginning of the Christmas Eve supper, accompanied by wishes for each other, expresses forgiving guilt and is a sign of willingness to be together. In Christianity it is a symbol of brotherhood, spiritual communion of members of the Church.
Sharing Christmas wafer (opłatek) is also practiced during Christmas meetings in companies, communities and institutions. Pink Christmas wafer is also manufactured. On Christmas Eve, farmers give it to domestic animals and cattle as a sign of union with all living beings.
Sharing the Christmas wafer (opłatek)

